# Using JQ to copy one field of an object into another

Tags: json, jq, edit

In my JSON are some objects with a `Description` property. How do I copy this value over to the `GMNotes` property of the same object using JQ?

In other words, how does one go from

```json
{
   "ObjectStates": [
      {
         "Description": "",
         "GMNotes": ""
      },
      {
         "Description": "foo",
         "GMNotes": ""
      }
   ]
}
```

to

```json
{
   "ObjectStates": [
      {
         "Description": "",
         "GMNotes": ""
      },
      {
         "Description": "foo",
         "GMNotes": "foo"
      }
   ]
}
```

`.ObjectStates[] | .GMNotes = .Description` only returns the modified objects, as shown in the [sandbox](https://jqplay.org/s/MjA2aFijGv).

(I could easily do this in Perl. The point is using `jq`.)

Comment: This was probably asked before, but I've had no luck finding it. Feel free to close as a dup if you can do better!

Comment: I'm also sure it has been asked before but it's indeed hard to search.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `map()` in combination with the *update assignment* operator `|=`:

```
jq '(.ObjectStates)|=map(.GMNotes=.Description)' file.json
```

https://jqplay.org/s/vFV_H4brlH

PS: instead of using `map` you could also just use the following command, the key is using `|=`.

```
jq '.ObjectStates[]|=(.GMNotes=.Description)' file.json
```

thanks chepner!

https://jqplay.org/s/NCGezXPjLE

Comment: The `|=` is the key thing; you can just use `.ObjectStates[] |= (.GMNotes = .Description)` as well.

Comment: Thanks. I had tried using `|=` instead of `=`, but not instead of `|`! This is perfect, and easily extensible to match my actual needs (`( ... ) |= ( .GMNotes = .Description )`).

Comment: `.ObjectStates  |= map_values( .GMNotes = .Description )` will also work